# angular ui-router, change screen but controller not

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular 1.5.2 and angular ui router 0.2.5, i make a page transition, from a state to another state, only the screen changes, but the controller not change, i tried to do the transition by three different ways:

```
              $location.path('/home');
              $state.go('home');
              $state.transitionTo('home');
```

the states

```
appTmw.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: '/components/login/loginview.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: '/components/home/homeView.html'
            },
            'nav@home': {
                templateUrl: '/assets/partials/cabecalho.html'
            },
            'rod@home': {
                templateUrl: '/assets/partials/rodape.html'
            }
        }
    })
    ...
```

The screen change from **login** to **home**, but the controller remains the **LoginCtrl**.

What is wrong with de code?

Comment: Please provide views names to all

Comment: And how do you know that the controller still remains `LoginCtrl`

Comment: Chandermani I note if a method declared in HomeCtrl not works, and i try to execute a method from LoginCtrl, and works, then, i take in mind that controller not change. Gary i dont understand what you mean, you want to see more code, or i need to speficy view name in another place of code?